# HtmlElement.InvokeMember, how wait until page loaded?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, browser, webbrowser-control

In my C# application I use WebBrowser object to read HTML include postbacks. To read default page by getting page I use WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler, like:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
wb.Navigate("http://example.com");
```

then in that event I have a page:

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    IsDocumentComplete = true;
    // here I can read the page
}
```

So, that event fires every time when I call Navigate method, but when I get some element on the page, invoke postback, I need to wait again until page loads again:

```
button.InvokeMember("onclick");
```

In that case wb_DocumentCompleted doesn't fire.

What is the way to know when page completely loaded.